# iOS Emulator for Windows

Tags: ios, macos

Is there any iOS emulator for Windows? I need one instead of the buying a macbook, just for that.I would like my tester to use it instead of buying a macbook.

Sorry for the noob question.

Comment: Even i dont own a macbook or imac. I use my teamviewer. however it is slow, but it works :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, the only official way is to buy an Mac for development. There's a thing called hackintosh, but I do not recommend installing software without licence for using it. Piracy is bad. Buy a Mac.

Comment: just testing.. my friend is a tester, need a emulator to test the codes we create...

Comment: There's no standalone simulator for any platform other than Mac OS X. Either you should buy a Mac or setup new Hakintosh on new/virtual machine. There's no other way - besides of obvious: buy used iPhone for your testers.

Comment: Hackintosh can be used with Offical purchase OSX cd.  You just need to install it on Intel based computers.

Comment: *"Piracy is bad. Buy a Mac."* Why would I invest **any** money in a company that's as monopolistic as Apple?

Comment: it's 2017 now... is there still no iOS emulator (like bluestack for Android) for windows yet?

Answer (score 1):

Hackintosh will help you :)
However if you are going to do programming on iOS/Mac: buy Mac ;)
http://www.hackintosh.com

Comment: no coding involved.. just testing...

Comment: can point me to correct point where i can download the emulator

Comment: You cannot install emulator only. Hackintosh allows you to install Mac OS X on your PC (not Mac) and then you will have access to iPhone emulator.